# Prove two real numbers $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x<y+e$ for every $e>0$ if and only if $x<y$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Having trouble proving this. I believe the proof is true, because if $x<y$, then it has to be true $x$ is still less than $y$ plus $e$ if $e$ is greater than 0. Not sure if a direct proof works or if I should go contradiction. In the converse, I think we would assume $x<y$ so then if $e>0$ then obviously $x<y+e$ but again I feel like this isn't a formal proof.

Comment: You can't: it's false. The condition should be $x\le y $

Comment: @Bernard that depends on the meaning of *two*

Comment: In this case, one usually says ‘two *distinct* numbers’.

Comment: Bernard Im confused why its false. If $x<y$ already, then adding a positive number to $y$ will still be true. Please correct me if im wrong in this assumption

Comment: Anyway, we have this definition: TWICE, adv. Once too often (Ambrose Bierce) ;o)

Comment: The l.h.s. is true if $x=y$. This is a well-known way to prove a nonstrict inequality.

Comment: Yes but since the r.h.s is if and only if, this condition would still work right?

Answer (score 1):

**Two non-equal real numbers $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x<y+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ if and only if $x<y$.**

This statement has two 'directions', tackle each direction separately.

**1. If  $x<y$**

Then, for any $\epsilon>0$,  $x<y<y+\epsilon$.

**1. If $x<y+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.**

Let  $\epsilon=\frac{x-y}{2}$.

Then $x<y+\epsilon=y+\frac{x-y}{2}=\frac{x+y}{2}$.

Since  $x<\frac{x+y}{2}$ we have $2x<x+y$.

Therefore $x<y$.